# Offcanvas transition doesnt works for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, css-transitions

I've a offcanvas navigation on the left which are working on chrome, IE, but not on Firefox. I know it's an issue with transition of the classes header, .sidebar, .viewport. I've try with the prefex and set the original parameter before transition.

```
header, .sidebar, .viewport {
    -webkit-transition:left .2s, right .2s;
    -moz-transition:left .2s, right .2s;
    -o-transition:left .2s, right .2s;
    -ms-transition:left .2s, right .2s;
    transition:left .2s, right .2s;
}
```

Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/P2QX9/ just make the window smaller to see the menu.

Many thx for your input.

Comment: Could explain the behavior you don't want further? They look the same to me

Comment: HI. The transition effect doesn't work in Firefox, but in Chrome yes.

Comment: But I'm saying in FF it looks the exact same as in Chrome. What version are you on? Is the transition not happening at all?

Comment: I'm using FF 25.0.1 on Windows 8.1 and on Windows 7. The transition is simply not happening on FF. It just open close like an on/off. On Opera 12.16 the menu doesnt open at all.